# get all distances from predict function

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I want to get **all distances** (confidence) from **predict function** so I decided to change the function but my program still uses the default function (I think it reads from dlls and libs)
so how can I **change a function** ? Should I use cmake ? If yes how ? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenCV doesn't provide a default function, you have to create your own by creating a vector which has distance and label. You can write your own function as below and store the distance and label in the vector. Here you need to rebuild the opencv.

```
virtual void predict(InputArray src, int &label, double &confidence,  Vector <variable>) const = 0;
```